# Need to use float, but sequence can't be multiplied as a result

Tags: python

I'm getting the error 'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' on the following line:

```
coef[i + 1] = coef[i + 1] + learning_rate * error * t_pred * (1 - t_pred) * row[i]
```

I can't change learning_rate to an int. It must be a float. With this restriction in mind, is there a workaround to this error?

Comment: It sounds like you're using lists where you should be using NumPy arrays somewhere.

Comment: One of those variables is a list, which one is it? What do you expect to happen when you multiply a list by a float? You should really post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One of your variables is type of non-int , therefore you get the error

Comment: Which one of those variables is a sequence then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `row[i]` is the sequence you can't multiply with a float, so just turn everything to an integer before the multiplication:

```
coef[i + 1] += int(learning_rate * error * t_pred * (1 - t_pred)) * row[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables are non-int type, when you do the math operations on them, it throws errors.

See an example here, use string 1 to multiply 1.0:

```
>>> "1" * 1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

You have to convert all your numeric strings to integer or float before do the math operations. You can use `type()` to check your variables types, for instance:  `type(learning_rate)`